# Join table with column. How is possible?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, persistence

Anybody to know something about this kind of queries:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = Account.GET_EXPIRATION_DATE, query="SELECT account.expirationDate FROM " +
        "Domain domain JOIN domain.account WHERE domain.id = :domainId"),
  @NamedQuery(name = Account.GET_BALANCE, query="SELECT account.balance FROM " +
  "Domain domain JOIN domain.account WHERE domain.id = :domainId")
})
```

I dont understand what is this "Domain domain JOIN domain.account" we can join one table with another but it seams we join table with column .. ?

these are the related classes:

```
package com.smsoffice.admin;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.*;

import com.smsoffice.billing.Account;
import com.smsoffice.billing.PrepaidAccount;


@Entity
@Table(name="DOMAIN")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name=Domain.GET_ALL_DOMAINS, query="SELECT d FROM Domain d ORDER BY d.name"),
  @NamedQuery(name=Domain.GET_ACCOUNT, query="SELECT d.account FROM Domain d WHERE d.id = :id"),
  @NamedQuery(name=Domain.GET_DOMAIN_BY_STATUS, query="SELECT d FROM Domain d WHERE d.enabled = :enabled ORDER BY d.name"),
  @NamedQuery(name=Domain.GET_DOMAIN_BY_NAME, query="SELECT d FROM Domain d WHERE d.name = :name")
})
public class Domain implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public final static String GET_ALL_DOMAINS = "Domain.getAllDomains";
  public final static String GET_ACCOUNT = "Domain.getAccount";

  public final static String GET_DOMAIN_BY_STATUS = "Domain.getAllDomainsByStatus";
  public final static String GET_DOMAIN_BY_NAME = "Domain.getDomainByName";

  public final static transient Domain ROOT = new Domain("ROOT");

  public static Domain SYSTEM_DOMAIN = new Domain("SYSTEM");

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(unique = true, length = 96)
  private String name;

  //unique id of the service - one per domain
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int serviceId;

  //indicates whether the domain is enabled
  private Boolean enabled = true;

  //short code for the domain sms events
  private int shortCode;

  //prefix for parsing 
  private String prefix;

  private String clientPrefix = "";

  //bank account
  @OneToOne(cascade = {PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE})
  private Account account = new PrepaidAccount();

  @OneToMany
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

  public Domain() {}

  public Domain(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getServiceId() {
    return serviceId;
  }

  public void setServiceId(int serviceId) {
    this.serviceId = serviceId;
  }

  public int getShortCode() {
    return shortCode;
  }

  public void setShortCode(int shortCode) {
    this.shortCode = shortCode;
  }

  public String getPrefix() {
    return prefix;
  }

  public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
  }

  public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
  }

  public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
  }

  public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }

    if (!(obj instanceof Domain)) {
      return false;
    }

    Domain domain = (Domain) obj;

    return getName().toUpperCase().equals(domain.getName().toUpperCase()); 
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return getName().toUpperCase().hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "[" + name + "("+ account + ")]";
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setClientPrefix(String clientPrefix) {
    this.clientPrefix = clientPrefix != null ? clientPrefix : "";
  }

  public String getClientPrefix() {
    return clientPrefix;
  }
}
```

and this one:

```
package com.smsoffice.billing;

import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = Account.GET_EXPIRATION_DATE, query="SELECT account.expirationDate FROM " +
        "Domain domain JOIN domain.account account WHERE domain.id = :domainId"),
  @NamedQuery(name = Account.GET_BALANCE, query="SELECT account.balance FROM " +
  "Domain domain JOIN domain.account account WHERE domain.id = :domainId")
})      
public abstract class Account {

  public static final MathContext MATH_CONTEXT = new MathContext(9, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  public static final int SCALE = 3;
  public static final int PRECISION = 9;

  public static final String GET_BALANCE = "Account.getBalance";

  public static final String GET_EXPIRATION_DATE = "Account.getExpirationDate";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(precision = PRECISION, scale = SCALE)
  protected BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

  @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
  protected Tariff tariff;

  private Date activationDate = new Date();

  private Date expirationDate;

  public Account() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    setExpirationDate(calendar.getTime());
  }

  public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public Tariff getTariff() {
    return tariff;
  }

  public void setTariff(Tariff tariff) {
      this.tariff = tariff;
  }

  void deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
    balance = balance.add(amount).setScale(SCALE, MATH_CONTEXT.getRoundingMode());
  }

  abstract boolean hasCredit(int eventCount);

  abstract void makePayment(int eventCount) throws PaymentException;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Date getActivationDate() {
    return activationDate;
  }

  public void setActivationDate(Date activationDate) {
    this.activationDate = normalizeActivationDate(activationDate);
  }

  void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
    this.expirationDate = normalizeExpirationDate(expirationDate);
  }

  public Date getExpirationDate() {
    return expirationDate;
  }

  public boolean isExpired() {

    Date now = new Date();

    return now.after(expirationDate);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "[balance: " + balance + "; tariff: " + (tariff != null ? tariff.getPrice() : "no tariff") + "; expiration date: " + expirationDate.toString() + "]"; 
  }

  public void setBalance(BigDecimal newBalance) {
    this.balance = newBalance;
  }

  private static final Date normalizeActivationDate(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
  }

  private static final Date normalizeExpirationDate(Date date) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);    
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
  }

}
```

Comment: It's somewhat silly. someone is aliasing the table "Domain" with an alias called "DOMAIN"  the second domain is simply a table alias.  it would also work if it was `domain as domain` or it would work without the second domain as well.  I don't really see  a reason to alias a table with the same name; other than to obfuscate what they are doing and confuse the issue.

Comment: ok this is silly I agree but my question is how I join domain with domain.account. What is domain.account ? Another table ? Subclass of domain or what ? It make sense if I join domain with address for example, but this ... wtf ?

Comment: how do you join it? How can anyone answer since you don't post the classes showing the relationships ?

Comment: These are JPQL queries, not SQL.  The queries are on the Account class, so apparently these queries use a domain.id to look up a domain, get the associated account instance and return the balance or expirationDate from it.  If you look at the Domain class, you would see a mapping for the 'account' that is likely a OneToOne or ManyToOne, and this mapping is what is joined over.  If you want the specific SQL used, turn on your providers SQL logging and execute the query.

Comment: sory my fault I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, these are not really SQL queries, but rather JPQL queries - there is a very good [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html) describing this, along with very nice examples. Note that in JPQL you do not work directly with the tables, bur rather with entities of your domain model.

But to your question, let's take this query as an example:

```
SELECT account.balance FROM Domain domain JOIN domain.account WHERE domain.id = :domainId
```

- `SELECT account.balance` will return the value of `balance` attribute of the account that was JOINed to the given domain record
- `FROM Domain domain` says that `Domain` entity will be used to query the data from related table, defined on the `Domain` entity using `@Table(name="DOMAIN")`; the lowercase `domain` is just an alias to be used within this query (see e.g. the WHERE portion of the query)
- `JOIN domain.account` will be used, together with annotation `@OneToOne(cascade = {PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE})` defined on the `account` field of `Domain` entity, to get the relevant record from the table represented by `Account` entity
- `WHERE domain.id = :domainId` will limit the results to return only the `Domain` with the given `id`, together with its `account`; the part `:domainId` is a "query parameter" and is most likely replaced somewhere in the code with an actual value, using code like `query.setParameter("domainId", someValue);`

So the whole query should return value of `BigDecimal` type (see field `balance` defined in `Account` entity).